# Installing 16.04 LTS on Intel NUC6i7KYK fails: mmc0 unknown controller version (3)

Tags: system-installation, live-usb

I've created a bootable USB stick (on a Mac) using UNetbootin USB installer. When I plug the USB stick in my Intel NUC6i7KYK and power up the NUC, I can make a selection from:

- 'Try Ubuntu without installing'
- 'Install Ubuntu'
- 'OEM install'
- 'Check disc for defects'

So it looks like the USB stick is detected and read. When I select the options for Try Ubuntu or Install Ubuntu, I get the message:

```
mmc0: unknown controller version (3). You may experience problems.
```

The latter is certainly true, because nothing happens after this: the screen turns black and stays that way.
Anybody having a clue?

Comment: Which version of BIOS do you have? Make sure you have the latest.

Comment: Or check for your System is compatible or too old but meets install 32bit.Lubuntu is not so heavy.Unity requires much more resources of your system.

Comment: I've upgraded the BIOS to the most recent version, so that should be ok. @MuditKapil: this NUC is the most recent Intel has. It contains an i7 processor, should be sufficient :-).